# Can I output audio to all three of my monitors?

Tags: audio, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi

I've seen this question asked tons of times, but it's never answered.

I'm looking to output audio from my computer, to THREE monitors simultaneously.

I don't want to use physical cables.

I've got a GTX670PE from MSI. I output to two monitors via DVI->HDMI, and one monitor from HDMI->HDMI. All three connections carry audio.

What I want to do, is somehow merge all three devices into one output device. I'm about to resort to a complicated system of VACs, but I've had issues with them before.

Any ideas? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't make Windows audio output to multiple devices without some kind of virtual / software getup like VACs.

I actually find VACs simpler to understand, but here's an alternative you might like to look into: https://youtu.be/BNhGRSc4oY0

It works pretty much the exact same way as VACs would, listening to one device and then pushing it back out to others.